# mysql peformance INSERT into table SELECT for report

Tags: mysql, insert, report, sql-optimization

I am working on a mysql query for a report.  The idea is to have a simple table say 'reportTable' with the values being fetched from various places.  I could then use the reportTable more easily without remembering lots of joins etc and also share this table for other projects.

1. Should I break down the inner insert part of the query so it does
   chunks at a time I will be adding probably tens of thousands of rows?

---

```
INSERT INTO reportTable
(
   -- long query grabbing results from various places
   SELECT var1 FROM schema1.table1
   SELECT var2 FROM schema2.table1
   SELECT var2 FROM schema2.table1
   etc
)
```

Comment: Only in that it will be temporary. Breaking it up into chunks isn't going to do anything for you, unless you it makes sense to read it mid-chunk.

Comment: I was toying with the idea of exporting it as a CSV file? and then re-importing it as a stream - however this seems redundant?  It could be large data volumes im dealing with?

Comment: The last thing you want to be doing with a large volume of data in a database is taking it out and putting it in again. How current does the data have to be. Would say the state of the database at close of play the day before do the job

Comment: It will be updated on a weekly or daily bases so does not need to be that current.

Comment: Why are you worried about optimising it then?. One over night scheduled stored procedure. Bob's your mother's sister's brother. Get the thing working the simplest way possible, then see if you need to get exceedingly clever.

Comment: I'm worried about crashing the DB server - its large amounts of data.  Does it load results into memory then insert?

Comment: It does what it has to get the job done. It might perform poorly depending on what you ask it to do, a crash though is extremely unlikely. This is premature optimisation. If you were talking millions of rows themn it would probably be better to go to some form of incremental process. Unless you were talking huuuuuuge though, be cheaper to throw a better machine at it than volunteer for that level of complexity. 1000s of rows is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addresses your concerns that inserting data takes too long and so on. I understood it like you rebuild your table each time. So, instead of doing so, just fetch the data that is new and not already in your table. Since looking up if the data is already present in your report table might be expensive, too, just get the delta. Here's how:

Make sure that in every table you need a column like this is present:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN created timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The `ON UPDATE` clause is of course optionally, don't know if you need to keep track of changes. If so, give me a comment and I can provide you with a solution with which you can keep a history of your data.

Now you need a small table that holds some meta information.

```
CREATE TABLE deltameta (tablename varchar(50), LSET timestamp, CET timestamp);
```

LSET is short for Last Successful Extraction Time, CET for Current Extraction Time.

When you get your data it works like this:

```
UPDATE deltameta SET CET = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE tablename = 'theTableFromWhichYouGetData';
SELECT @varLSET := LSET, @varCET := CET FROM deltameta WHERE tablename = 'theTableFromWhichYouGetData';
INSERT INTO yourReportTable (
    SELECT whatever FROM aTable WHERE created >= @varLSET AND created < @varCET
);
UPDATE deltameta SET LSET = CET WHERE tablename = 'theTableFromWhichYouGetData';
```

When anything goes wrong during inserting your script stops and you get the same data the next time you run it. Additionally you can work with transactions here, if you need to roll back. Again, write a comment if you need help with this.

Comment: hi thanks for the heads up with this.  However im looking for info on insert options.

Comment: What insert options? I already had trouble to figure out what you're after before your comment, can you please phrase a clear question again?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion and again thanks for your time.  I need to populate a table called reportTable.  The data fetched comes from various other tables (query to generate it is quite long).  The idea is to have a simle reportTable that I can re-use across several reports.

However I dont know what is the best option for me to insert the data into the new table especially as I will be using large amounts of data.

Comment: So what are you hoping for? Some kind of switch which lets you insert really fast? Just let the DB do what it has to do. If your SELECTs are slow, that's a different question and the indexes and/or queries have to be investigated in detail. But apart from running out of disk space there is no reason why your server should crash just because of inserting much data. Exporting/Importing data is nonsense, don't worry about memory or whatever. If anything goes wrong or takes too long, you have to show us the queries and tables in detail.

Comment: If it was to take 2 hours to run etc would there be anyway to estimate the time or get a status on its progress?

Comment: Unfortunately no, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but you seem to be talking about a basic view. You can read an introduction to views here: http://techotopia.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_MySQL_Views, and here are the mysql view docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I don't think a view is what im after I need a table that exists as a report base that other queries can be run against such as bookings in a month bookings per location etc.  I also need it to be fast the view would be quite slow for my needs.

Comment: @NickMitchinson No materialized views in MySQL.